# Target 2 elements in CSS in a list

Tags: css-selectors

In a ul/li of 20 elements, how to target 2 concurrent elements out of 4 elements starting with the 2nd in the list (1 / 2+3 / 4 / 5 / 6+7 / 8 / 9 / 10+11 etc).

I try with the :nth-child rule but I can't do it. I can't find a rule with different values.

Regards.
Jean

Comment: Depending on your use case it might make sense to group them in the markup instead, then it's trivial to style them how you want. But I'm not sure if there's a clean CSS-only solution to this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The ul/li is a dynamic data from WordPress CPT source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply combine two CSS selectors to accomplish this. Comma separated CSS selectors will both be matched separately for the rules block.

```css
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
}

li:nth-child(4n+2), li:nth-child(4n+3) {
  background-color: #ffcccc;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Momofr Glad to hear! Please mark the answer as accepted so it will help others in the future.